# Why size of image is not same when i download an image from a url?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, bitmapfactory

I am downloading an image from a url and create a bitmap image in my android app. Size of image is 126 kb. When i create an image in my app by downloading it from url then size is around 3.25 mb. I am using following code to downlad image from url:

```
URL urlConnection = new URL(imageUrl);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

Why downloaded size of image is bigger and is there any way to download it in the same size? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The downloaded size is not bigger. You converted the downloaded bytes after download to a bitmap. And yes then they occupy more memory. What i miss in your post is how you know that it is 3.25 MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image you download is probably in some compressed format (.jpg .png). Bitmap you get from BitmapFactory.decodeStream on the other hand is in uncompressed format. 
If you dont need to show your bitmap in original resolution you can scale it down ([detailed instructions here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)). Otherwise such memory usage is normal.

Answer (score 1):

Android converts this image to bmp. You can convert it by youself and you get size ~3.5 mb.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use Bitmapfactory for downloads. Use an InputStream and a FileOutputStream to save to internal, external or removable memory directly.

Comment: Any clue to _why_? And any answer to his direct question on why it's different?

Comment: Please read the other comments. The image is not only downloaded. But after that converted to a bitmap.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't asking really - I meant that as a pointer to improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Image size depends on bits per pixel .during conversion you have to give bits per pixel
file size is given by Resolution^2 x Width x Height x Bits per sample ÷ 8,192